# programatically access the value of a prop in svelte

Tags: svelte

I have a component that I have programatically instantiated, like this:

```
const form = new FormElement({
   target: options.el,
   props: { ...options },
});
```

How can I get the value of a prop? something like `form.props.editable`, or `form.$get('editable')` or similar

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you either need to set the `accessors` option or export a function/object from the component:

```html
<!-- In the component -->
<svelte:options accessors />
```

Access then would be directly `form.editable`.

You can also export functions/object from the script block that wrap any props, e.g.

```js
export function getEditable() { return editable }
export const api = {
    get editable() { return editable; },
};
```

They also can be called directly (`form.getEditable()`/`form.api.editable`).

[REPL with examples](https://svelte.dev/repl/4b36ce638a9044c2b2432615d20eacbc?version=3.47.0)

Comment: How can you set the accessors only when rendering the component for unit testing?

Comment: @Yulian: `accessors` should be forceable as [a compiler option](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/82d2982845df188631993db6b18c2842e3613acf/src/compiler/interfaces.ts#L176), ideally your test tools allow you to set that for testing purposes, so it depends on where/how the components are compiled.